# Проблема с загрузкой и сохранением GameObject[] в XML файл

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть код который сохраняет массив объектов в xml и код который загружает, но в процессе что идёт не так и rotation объектов загружается не так.То есть position загружаются верно а rotation загружаются не верно

```
   public void SaveDesginXsml_Test(GameObject[] obj)
    {

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Desgin");
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
        for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
        {
            if (obj[i] != null)
            {
                Vector3 trans = obj[i].transform.position;

                XmlNode userNode;
                userNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Deteil");
                rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);
                XmlNode parameter;

                parameter = xmlDoc.CreateElement("name" + i);
                parameter.InnerText = obj[i].GetComponent<Detail>().ID.ToString();
                userNode.AppendChild(parameter);

                parameter = xmlDoc.CreateElement("x_pos" + i);
                parameter.InnerText = trans.x.ToString();
                userNode.AppendChild(parameter);

                parameter = xmlDoc.CreateElement("y_pos" + i);
                parameter.InnerText = trans.y.ToString();
                userNode.AppendChild(parameter);

                parameter = xmlDoc.CreateElement("z_pos" + i);
                parameter.InnerText = trans.z.ToString();
                userNode.AppendChild(parameter);

                parameter = xmlDoc.CreateElement("x_rot" + i);
                parameter.InnerText = obj[i].transform.rotation.x.ToString();//WrapAngle(obj[i].transform.localEulerAngles.x).ToString();
                userNode.AppendChild(parameter);

                Debug.Log(obj[i].transform.rotation.x.ToString());
                Debug.Log(obj[i].transform.rotation.y.ToString());
                Debug.Log(obj[i].transform.rotation.z.ToString());

                parameter = xmlDoc.CreateElement("y_rot" + i);
                parameter.InnerText = obj[i].transform.rotation.y.ToString();//WrapAngle(obj[i].transform.localEulerAngles.y).ToString();
                userNode.AppendChild(parameter);

                parameter = xmlDoc.CreateElement("z_rot" + i);
                parameter.InnerText = obj[i].transform.rotation.z.ToString();//WrapAngle(obj[i].transform.localEulerAngles.z).ToString();
                userNode.AppendChild(parameter);

            }
        }
        xmlDoc.Save("Data/Save.xml");
    }
```

```
 public void LoadDesgin_Test()
    {
        clearGarage(craft);
       
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            Vector3 kek = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
            string _name = "";
            // Debug.Log(i);
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("Data/Save.xml");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement("name" + i))
                {
                    _name = reader.ReadString();
                   // Debug.Log(_name);
                }
                if (reader.IsStartElement("x_pos" + i) && !reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                    //Debug.Log(reader.ReadString());
                    kek.x = float.Parse(reader.ReadString());
                    
                }
                if (reader.IsStartElement("y_pos" + i) && !reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                   // Debug.Log(reader.ReadString());
                    kek.y = float.Parse(reader.ReadString());

                }
                if (reader.IsStartElement("z_pos" + i) && !reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                   // Debug.Log(reader.ReadString());
                    kek.z = float.Parse(reader.ReadString());

                }
                if (reader.IsStartElement("x_rot" + i) && !reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                   // Debug.Log(reader.ReadString());
                    rot.x = float.Parse(reader.ReadString());

                }
                if (reader.IsStartElement("y_rot" + i) && !reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                   // Debug.Log(reader.ReadString());
                    rot.y = float.Parse(reader.ReadString());

                }
                if (reader.IsStartElement("z_rot" + i) && !reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                   // Debug.Log(reader.ReadString());
                    rot.z = float.Parse(reader.ReadString());
                    reader.Close();
                }
                // reader.Close();
            }
            trans.position = kek;
            //Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
           
            GameObject det = dm.Get_GameObject_from_ID(_name);
          //  Debug.Log(dm.Get_GameObject_from_ID(_name));
            if (det != null)
            {
               // trans.Rotate(rot);
                Debug.Log(rot.x);
                Debug.Log(rot.y);
                Debug.Log(rot.z);
                gm = Instantiate(det, trans.position, trans.rotation);

               gm.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(gm.transform.rotation, rot, 1.0f);

            }

        }
        //reader.Close();
    }
```

```
<Desgin>
  <Deteil>
    <name0>rama_4x4</name0>
    <x_pos0>2,419504</x_pos0>
    <y_pos0>0,9200001</y_pos0>
    <z_pos0>36,36234</z_pos0>
    <x_rot0>0</x_rot0>
    <y_rot0>-0,7125125</y_rot0>
    <z_rot0>0</z_rot0>
  </Deteil>
  <Deteil>
    <name1>rama_4x4</name1>
    <x_pos1>0,008971095</x_pos1>
    <y_pos1>0,9200003</y_pos1>
    <z_pos1>34,54207</z_pos1>
    <x_rot1>0</x_rot1>
    <y_rot1>0</y_rot1>
    <z_rot1>0</z_rot1>
  </Deteil>
  <Deteil>
    <name2>rama_4x4</name2>
    <x_pos2>1,971091</x_pos2>
    <y_pos2>0,9200001</y_pos2>
    <z_pos2>32,96392</z_pos2>
    <x_rot2>0</x_rot2>
    <y_rot2>0</y_rot2>
    <z_rot2>0</z_rot2>
  </Deteil>
  <Deteil>
    <name3>rama_4x4</name3>
    <x_pos3>4,007107</x_pos3>
    <y_pos3>0,9200003</y_pos3>
    <z_pos3>34,44344</z_pos3>
    <x_rot3>0</x_rot3>
    <y_rot3>0</y_rot3>
    <z_rot3>0</z_rot3>
  </Deteil>
</Desgin>
```

Я уже очень замучался...

Comment: Было бы неплохо пример XML и тех значений, которые получаются по факту в Rotation (с явным указанием того, что должно быть)

Comment: Как вы поняли, что `загружается не так`? И сразу второй вопрос: почему не JSON?

Comment: Вы полагаете, мы можем угадать, что именно значит "не так"? Приведите конкретные примеры: выгрузил так, загрузилось вот так - неправильно вот это. Пока что можно много описывать как сильно вы замучались, но лучше добавить деталей по сути вопроса.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу @aepot. Весь мир сидит на `json`, забыв про `xml`.

Comment: Дополнил, исправил я подумал что xml проще

Comment: кратко XML vs JSON: 1) XML сложнее, структура, чтение, всё сложнее 2) Обработка XML кушает раза в 3 больше памяти, практически независимо от платформы и языка разработки 3) Инструменты для сериализации удобнее именно у JSON. P.S. Если вам нужна вся мощь при работе с JSON, доступная в Unity, ставьте NuGet пакет Newtonsoft.Json и развлекайтесь. [Но есть и встроенные средства](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/12888024) + [документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html).

Answer (score 2):

Опишу ошибки, которые видны с первого взгляда.

`for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)` - в методе записи,
`for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)` - в методе чтения.
Почему в одном месте 80, в другом 40?

По идее, при записи должно быть `for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++)` - проходим по всему массиву.
А читать нужно, пока в файле есть данные.

---

Почему при записи вы используете `XmlDocument`, а при чтении `XmlTextReader`? Будьте последовательны и в обоих случаях применяйте либо создание документа в памяти, либо потоковые средства.

Кстати, оба они являются устаревшими. Вместо первого следует использовать `XDocument/XElement` (технология LINQ to XML), вместо второго - `XmlReader`.

---

В коде чтения видим:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    ...
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("Data/Save.xml");
```

Вы 40 раз создаёте ридер и читаете один и тот же файл. Явно логика работы нарушена.

---

Проще всего выкинуть весь этот код и использовать (де)сериализацию. Смотрите класс `XmlSerializer`.

Как вам подсказывают в комментариях, уже происходит отказ от XML и переход на JSON. Советую прислушаться к этим советам.

---

Используйте нормальные говорящие имена переменных! Вот что означают все эти ваши `kek`, `obj`, `det`?